# Get id for each element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have blog post list and that post have comments. Posts and comments i loop with `foreach` from database.So i have problem when i want to create new comment via ajax. I have form and one hidden field for holding post id. 
When from jquery i try to access to that element `post_id` is all time the some. I try on submit to debug with alert to see witch `post_id` will be returned. All time return 270. And when i click to other post comment submit id is not changed.

**Posts and comments**

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   <h1><?= $post->title; ?></h1>
    <p><?= $post->text; ?></p>
    <?= if($comments = postComments($post->id): ?>
        <?= foraech($comments as $comment): ?>
             <form id="post_add">
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Say somthing..." name="comment">
                  <input type="hidden" name="pid" class="pid" value="<?= $post->id">
                  <input type="submit">
             </form>
         <?= endforeach; ?>
    <?= endif; ?>
<?= endforeach; ?>



submiteComment: function() {

        var comment_form = $("#comment_add");
        var comment_text = $(".comment_text");
        var pid = $(".pid");  // post id

        $("body").on("submit", comment_form, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert(pid.val()); // debug all time return 270 for all comments

            if($.trim(comment_text).length) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: baseurl + '/comment/create',
                    data: {item_id: post_id.val(), comment_text: comment_text.val()},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function(t, r, j) {
                        alert(r.responseText);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you able to fetch post_ids from database properly?

Comment: $(".pid").val() return last element match with this class.So you have to loop to get all elements of that class.

Comment: when you create new comment increment your post_id by one every time according to last  post_id

Comment: @ShivaniPatel No. It will return the first match, not the last.

Comment: Guys i dont complicate things. I have 300 posts in database and i just want to access to their ID over hidden box.  All posts is fetchend and work, all comments is fetchend and work. When i clik on some post i try to show `alert` with post id.

Comment: Can you show `#comment_add` form? What is `<form id="post_add">`, and why it in `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving each of the post id fields in the form the same name and class, when you access it like this:

`var pid = $(".pid");`

You will receive all three of the pid elements for your comments into the variable pid. When you do `pid.val()` it will just return the value of the first one, which is why you will always be seeing the same pid no matter which comment you submit.